# Why does the object I usee to store data from a loop throw an error?

Tags: r, netlogo

```
nruns <- 100
NLCommand("set N-turtles 100")
for(i in 1:nruns) {
NLCommand("setup")
NLDoCommandWhile("count turtles > 99", "go", max.minutes=0)
timetaken[[i]]<-NLReport("ticks")}
timetaken
```

This code throws an error at the timetaken section saying:

```
Error in timetaken[[i]] <- NLReport("ticks") : 
  object 'timetaken' not found
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: You didn't create `timetaken` before the loop. The object must exist if you want to assign a value to it.

Comment: add "timetaken <- numeric(nruns)" before your loop or whatever type the result of  NLReport("ticks") is

Comment: @etienne "The object must exist if you want to assign a value to it" is totally wrong in R. For instance `a<-1` works, even if `a` wasn't created. What you can't do is to _subset_ an object if it doesn't exist or assigning a value to a subset of it (as the OP tried to do).

Comment: @nicola: by object I meant the one used by the OP so timetaken here. I should have used a better formulation

Comment: @nist that works perfectly. For some reason the code worked yesterday but I must have assigned it the first time it gave the error so it worked thereafter. Thanks to everyone for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line suggested in the comments works as an answer to my question.

```
timetaken <- numeric(nruns)
```